# Upgrading manually Mesa3D in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mesa

I'm trying to compile and build `Mesa3`D version `10.2.` but **./configure** complains about `libdrm_radeon >= 2.4.54`(Currently there is the 2.4.52 installed).

So I tried to manually upgrade `libdrm`, following the steps in http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/libdrm.html...

Everything worked without errors, but still Mesa's configure complains about version of `libdrm`

I'm not a linux expert, so I'm not able to understand what's going wrong. Some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

after you ran

```
make install
```

of the libdrm package?

Either this or reboot your computer..